# Handling possible nil date from array of objects from db which may return a date

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to objective c and have been given an existing, outsourced codebase so I apologise if I am missing something very obvious!

I have a Goal data model which I have added a date to:
[image: GoalDataModel]

When making a request to the db for an array of goals, the following is returned:
[image: GoalArray]

As you can see, one of the array elements returns an extra KVP which is the date type I added to the xcdatamodel previously. This date refers to the date in which the goal was completed.
[image: Goal]

When iterating over this array in a for loop and checking whether the date KVP is not nil, NULL is returned for the object in which the date exists for:

```
([[self.goalArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"date"] != nil) ?
[[self.goalArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"date"] : [NSNull null]
```

However, the other values in the object using the same above expression with their keys return their expected values:
[image: ArrayReturn]

It's worth noting that in order to get the app to run, I change the date xcdatamodel to a string value as opposed to date for testing purposes.

I have also added this to the Goal model:

```
@synthesize date;
...
-(NSDate*) date {
    return date;
}

-(void) setDate:(NSDate*)DateTime {
    date = DateTime;
}
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing as I am at a wits end?
Again I apologise if this is a bad question I cannot find any clues as to how to handle objects which may or may not return a certain KVP

Comment: FYI - use `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:` to get an object from an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `objectForKey:`, that's a `NSDictionary` function. The `valueForKey:` basically works on any class and returns a value and/or function result based on the key you pass it.

I can imagine something funky happening when asking for the date.

Your code should probably look somewhat like the following:

```c
NSDictionary *goalInfo = self.goalArray[i];
//goalInfo[@"date"] - This is the short, and more readable version of 'objectForKey:'

if (goalInfo && goalInfo[@"date"]) {
  return goalInfo[@"date"];
}
else {
  return [NSNull null];
}
```